# vb.net How to get working scrollbars when moving nested form controls inside a parent panel

Tags: vb.net, controls, nested, scrollbar, move

I have a container (a panel) which can contain multiple Form controls.
(Form.TopLevel = False)

When the user moves the Forms around I would like to display scrollbars when a form is out of the panel bounds.

When I register the Form.Move event, I can set the AutoScrollPosition. This works unless the user uses the scrollbars.
The problem is that the form.move event is also fired when the scrollbars are used. The result is that the scrollbars don't work. (And I have currently no idea how to find out whether the form has been moved by the mouse or by the scrollbar)

So the question is: How can I make the scrollbars of the panel appear/work when a form (or multiple) forms of the panel exceed the boundaries? I think there must be a simpler way than to handle the move event..

Note:
The panel is placed inside a Infragistics DockableControlPane. (Managed by an UltraDockManager)
(So there are multiple panels which contain at least one form per panel)
The reason is that the "panels" should appear as tabs, can be moved around using the DockManager and display their "sub" forms (Which also can be moved around on their panel).

Any idea would be great

Comment: This is a very questionable UI feature.  Just because you *can* move the form around doesn't automatically makes it useful to let the user tinker with it.  The form's title bar never drawing itself with the window activated style is also very confusing to users.  Design a UI that allows the user to easily scroll to whatever element she needs to get at.  A form with TopLevel = False should also have FormBorderStyle = None.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply.
Thats currently the way the application should look like. All forms of a tab belong to a certain group e.g "Order" and the user wants so see all order relevant infos. (Wich are currently displayed in separate forms) Maybe we change the behavior later on but currently I have to work with movable forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the LocationChanged event could be used.  Example with only one form:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)

  Dim f As New Form
  f.TopLevel = False
  AddHandler f.LocationChanged, AddressOf Form_LocationChanged
  Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
  f.Show()
  Call Form_LocationChanged(f, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  With DirectCast(sender, Form)
    Panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = New Size(.Bounds.Right, .Bounds.Bottom)
  End With
End Sub
```

Using an MDI form seems to be more appropriate though for something like this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your solution worked! My first try was also the LocatioChanged event, but it didn't work So I switched to the move event. Thanks a lot!